# how to have memecached server keep started

Tags: php

I am using memecached  to store values. I its working fine when start and inset key value pair in one file but when I do this In obj orienter approach  its not working fine, I think I am doing something wrong while starting server but not sure what

**cache.php**

```
class cache{

   function __construct($id = 'someid')
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->obj = new Memcached($id);


        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->port = '11211';

        $this->connect($this->host,$this->port  );
    }

    public function connect($host , $port )
    {
        $servers = $this->obj->getServerList();
        if (is_array($servers)) {
            foreach ($servers as $server)
                if ($server['host'] == $host and $server['port'] == $port)
                    return true;
        }
        return $this->obj->addServer($host, $port);
    }

   public function add($key, $value)
    {
            $this->obj->add($key, $value);

    }
  public function get($key)
   {
         return $this->obj->get($key);
   }

}
```

and than I am calling it in another class

***abc.php***

```
require 'cache.php';
class abc
{
    private $cache;

    public function __construct()
    {
           $this->cache = new cache();

    }

    public function addval($keyname, $value){
        $this->cache->add($keyname, $value);

    }
    public function getCachedVal($keyname)
    {

        $this->cache->get($keyname));

    }


}
```

now in **index.php** I am calling **abc.php**

```
$a = new abc()
$a->addval('demo','hellothisis');
var_dump($a->getCachedVal('demo'));
```

but I am getting

> NULL

also I am passing passing id here `Memcached($id);`  so I don't think my old instance will get destroyed

also I have server started

```
 array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port"]=> int(11211) } }
```

Comment: What's your `memeCaching` class?

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry cache was the memeCaching class ( typo while I was writing here)

Comment: Where did `vgetCachedVal()` come from? Are you sure this is the code you're using?

Comment: @Sjon it was an typo, corrected now

Comment: What is the return value of `$this->cache->add($keyname, $value);`? If `demo` already exists in memcache from previous testing then `add` will not overwrite it with your value. Consider `$this->cache->set($keyname, $value);` instead.

Comment: I think you are missing return in getCachedVal